# run command cucumber version fail ,

Tags: android, automated-tests, cucumber, calabash-android

I try to work with cucumber / calabash-android , but I face a problem Unable to activate calabash-android-0.9.2, because json-2.1.0 conflicts with json (~> 1.8) ? , I tried to unistall cucmber and install it .[image]

Answer (score 0):

Calabash Android and iOS do not support json 2.1 - they are pinned to json 1.8.

If your ruby does not support json 1.8, you should downgrade to ruby 2.3.x.

Answer (score 0):

The most recommended Ruby version for using Calabash gems is still the v2.3.1. As I see, you use rbenv. That's nice, install that version and set as global default:

```
rbenv install 2.3.1
rbenv global 2.3.1
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

Use bundler to determine which gem versions you want to use in Ruby projects. Install bundler:

```
gem install bundler
```

Make a `Gemfile` with the following contents:
(You can create a skeleton with the `bundler init` command too.)

```
source "https://rubygems.org"

gem 'calabash-android', '~> 0.9.2'
gem 'calabash-cucumber', '~> 0.21.4'
gem 'cucumber', '~> 2.4'
gem 'json', '~> 1.8.6', '< 2.0'
```

Install the specified gems with bundler (if you change `Gemfile`, you have to run again):

```
bundle install
```

Run Ruby project with this configuration:

```
bundle exec calabash-android run myApp.apk
```

Small explanation for `Gemfile`:

- `~>` relation allows minor updates only
- `>=` means you will get major updates too
- or you can define a version exactly: `gem 'json', '1.8.6'`

The json 1.8.6 is the latest version which works for me.

https://rubygems.org/gems/json/versions